# JSF selectOneMenu select a item, inputText's readOnly property changes

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu and a InputText. I want to change  `readOnly="false"` property of InputText when I select other option of selectOneMenu.

These are codes

```
<h:form>    
    <h:selectOneMenu id="customerCombo"
                     value="#{customer.selectedBank}"
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Please select one">

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seçiniz" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{customer.banks}" />         
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Other" itemLabel="Other"/> 

        <f:validateRequired/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:message for="customerCombo"/>
    <br /><br />

    <h:outputText value="other text" />

    <h:inputText id="digerText" readonly="true"/>

    <br /><br />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="customerResult" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: It may be easier to use the `onchange` property of the `selectOneMenu` to trigger a change in the `disabled` property of an `inputText` via javascript.

Comment: Please, Do you show me how to do that.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: No, absolutely don't do that. This wouldn't take JSF state into account.

Comment: What JSF framework are you using?

Comment: JSF framework is 2.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a variable in your `@ViewScoped` backing bean that will correspond to the readOnly state

   ```
   private boolean readOnly;
   //getter and setter
   ```
2. Define a method that will toggle the state of the `readOnly` variable. This method will be called via ajax

   ```
   public void toggleReadOnly(){
       if(selectedBank.equals("Other"){
         readOnly = true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Bind the value of the readOnly variable to the `<h:inputText/>`

   ```
    <h:inputText id="digerText" readonly="#{bean.readOnly}"/>
   ```

   `bean` being (hehe) the name of your backing bean
4. Trigger the `toggleReadOnly` method from your dropdown menu

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu id="customerCombo"
                value="#{customer.selectedBank}"
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please select one">
       <f:ajax listener="#{bean.toggleReadOnly}" render="digerText"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```